# Capybara: How do I fill in a input field by its ID

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have this:

```
<input class="string optional" 
    id="course_group_courses_attributes_2_name" 
    name="course_group[courses_attributes][2][name]" 
    placeholder="Lengua" 
    size="15" 
    type="text" />
</div>
```

How do I fill in a that field by its ID?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`fill_in` accepts the id as first parameter:

```
fill_in 'course_group_courses_attributes_2_name', :with => 'some text'
```

Comment: I thought so, but It is not working. It seems that it doesn't fill it. It doesn't give any errors about not finding it. It just doesn't fill it.

Comment: Maybe you can include the capybara code in question and any other related code.

Comment: I discovered that the problem where in Mongoid. Release candidates bugs.

Comment: @Nerian ah! glad you figured it out

Comment: have we got the solution?

Comment: @raidfive what should be the name for describe? like describe User do or something else ?

Answer (score 35):

You can also do it with:

```
find('Id or class here').set('some text')
```

Answer (score 8):

`fill_in` accepts id without the # symbol which I found confusing at first.  Also note that if your input field is in a modal, you may need to wait for the transition or fade in before the field can be filled in.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using **simple_form** gem then you must note that it does automatically id your form elements, hence manually id-ing elements yourself is futile!

There is; however, a naming convention that simple_form follows to id form elements.

```
object_attribute
```

So if you're filling-in information for let's say a contact object as follows:

```
= simple_form_for @contact do |f|
  = f.input :first_name
  = f.input :last_name
```

simple_form will then automatically generate ids to each form element respectively as so:

```
id="contact_first_name"
id="contact_last_name"
```

Now you can simply make use of this naming convention to fulfill all your fill_in needs. Hope this helps.